# Why I can't catch an exception thrown from third party library?

Tags: c#, exception

Using using third party library I experience interesting situation. The following code breaks on exception:

```
var instance = new Class(arg);
```

But when this line is enclosed in `try/catch` block, the exception is never caught.

Of course, the visual studio debugger stops on the exception only when the break on given exception type is enabled. When disabled, the exception disappears (at all). The catch block is never executed. Does not matter if `catch (Exception exc) {}` or `catch {}` is used. The exception is derived from `Exception`.

**How is this possible?**

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the behavior of "break on given exception type".  This is a feature of the debugger to break even on handled exceptions.  The library is catching and "handling" the exception.  Your catch block is not hit because because it's already been caught.  If you had the source of the library, you'd break at a different point.

Comment: This was second and last attempt to share the stuff I had to think a bit of in a Q&A style ;) Anyway, you are right at the point the exception is handled, and as I have decompiled the library, it is handled in the way I described in the answer. Firstly it seemed a bit odd to me, so I made a conclusion, it is just "debug only" exception. The given class is called AForge.FilterInfoCollection and resides in AForge.Video.DirectShow.dll, if you want to take a look (www.aforgenet.com). Maybe the formulation and the simplification attempts seem too stupid and I again got some down-votes.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone down voted the question, but I'm guessing the down vote on the answer came from someone burned by empty catch blocks.  Unfortunately, I too have found many catch blocks that are empty or have a single comment like "// TODO: figure out what to do with errors".  You probably just caused an emotional response.  I gave it a +1 to get back to 0.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose this might be common trick or practice to have "debug only" exceptions. The third party library uses code like this:

```
public class Class
{
    public Class(object arg)
    {
        try
        {
           ...
           throw new Exception("message");
           ...
        }
        catch
        {
            // This is just empty. By purpose.
        }
        finally
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The debugger then stops on the throw statement (if configured to do so), but as the exception is "handled", it does not propagate anywhere else...